# How to unzip aecdump from chrome://webrtc-internals/?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, webrtc

Possible duplicate but I could not find an answer.

I am trying to record output of a webRTC call for audio quality analysis. Enabling "diagnostic audio recordings" in chrome://webrtc-internals/ currently creates a .wav file and an AEC_DUMP file. How do I go about extracting the input and output audio from this?

Resources on the internet state: `Use the unpack_aecdump (it should be on out/Debug or out/Release if you compile all the targets.)`

What is unpack_aecdump? Where is this out/Debug or out/Release directory and with what do I compile this?

Cheers!